# How to make a histogram in r studio, but with rows values

Tags: r, graph, histogram

The csv file is like this

```
    Country   x2012   x2013  x2014
1   Afghanistan 0.1   0.2    0.3
2   Argentina   0.4   0.5    0.6
```

I want to create a histogram with the numbers of Argentina that only takes x2013 and x2014, how can I do it??

Comment: `hist(df[df$country == "Argentina", c("x2013", "x2014"])` does that do as expected? Can post as a more detailed answer if so.

Comment: I removed the tags [tag:rstudio] (that's an IDE, not the language) and [tag:rstudio-server] (that's a commercial product for a web-based version of the same IDE). If this is in error, my apologies, but if so please help me understand how they are correct. Thanks!